# Mathematical equation of binomial probit gam (mgcv) with tensor product interactions?

Tags: equation, interaction, gam, mgcv, binomial-coefficients

I have the following binomial (probit) gam using mgcv, which includes y (0 or 1), two continuous predictors (xa, xb) plus the ‘ti’ interactions of a third covariate (xc) with these two predictors.

```
mygam <- gamV(y ~ s(xa, k=10, bs="cr") + s(xb, k=10, bs="cr") +
                  ti(xc, xa, bs = c("cr", "cr"), k = c(5, 5)) +
                  ti(xc, xb, bs = c("cr", "cr"), k = c(5, 5)),
                data = df, method = "ML", family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

Using default k=10 for main effects and k=c(5,5) for interactions, the intercept and 50 coefficients are the following:

```
terms <- c("Intercept", "s(xa).1", "s(xa).2", "s(xa).3", "s(xa).4", "s(xa).5", "s(xa).6", "s(xa).7", "s(xa).8", "s(xa).9", "s(xb).1", "s(xb).2", "s(xb).3", "s(xb).4", "s(xb).5", "s(xb).6", "s(xb).7", "s(xb).8", "s(xb).9", "ti(xc,xa).1", "ti(xc,xa).2", "ti(xc,xa).3", "ti(xc,xa).4", "ti(xc,xa).5", "ti(xc,xa).6", "ti(xc,xa).7", "ti(xc,xa).8", "ti(xc,xa).9", "ti(xc,xa).10", "ti(xc,xa).11", "ti(xc,xa).12", "ti(xc,xa).13", "ti(xc,xa).14", "ti(xc,xa).15", "ti(xc,xa).16", "ti(xc,xb).1", "ti(xc,xb).2", "ti(xc,xb).3", "ti(xc,xb).4", "ti(xc,xb).5", "ti(xc,xb).6", "ti(xc,xb).7", "ti(xc,xb).8", "ti(xc,xb).9", "ti(xc,xb).10", "ti(xc,xb).11", "ti(xc,xb).12", "ti(xc,xb).13", "ti(xc,xb).14", "ti(xc,xb).15", "ti(xc,xb).16")

coefs <- c(-0.0702421404106311, 0.0768316292916553, 0.210036768213672, 0.409025596435604, 0.516554288252813, 0.314600352165584, -0.271938137725695, -1.1169186662112, -1.44829172827383, -2.39608336269616, 0.445091855160863, 0.119747299507175, -0.73508332280573, -1.3851857008194, -1.84125850675114, -1.77797283303084, -1.45118023146655, -1.56696555281429, -2.55103708393941, 0.0505422263407052, -0.110361707609838, -0.168897589312596, -0.0602318423244818, 0.095385784704545, -0.20818521830706, -0.318650042681766, -0.113613570916751, 0.123559386280642, -0.269467853796075, -0.412476320830133, -0.147039497705579, 0.189416535823022, -0.412990646359733, -0.632158143648671, -0.225344249076957, 0.0237165469278517, 0.0434926950921869, 0.080572361088243, 0.397397459143317, 0.0453636001566695, 0.0831126054198634, 0.153350111096294, 0.75009880522662, 0.0583689328419794, 0.107001374561518, 0.197852239031467, 0.970623037721609, 0.0894562434842868, 0.163989821269297, 0.303175057387294, 1.48718228468607)

df_coefs <- data.frame(terms, coefs)
```

I would like the mathematical equation of this model, which would allow to determine the probability of y given known covariates. Given as example from my dataset (n > 70000), the predicted probability ‘prob’ (type = “response”) obtained with xa = 7.116, xb = 2.6, and xc = 19 was prob = 0.76444141, which is the result to be determined with the expected mathematical equation.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help and time.

Below, the summary(mygam)

```
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate    Std. Error  z value     Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.07024    0.00709     -9.907      <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
          edf       Ref.df  Chi.sq      p-value    
s(xa)     8.007     8.548   5602.328    < 2e-16 ***
s(xb)     8.448     8.908   16282.793   < 2e-16 ***
ti(xc,xa) 1.004     1.007   10.278      0.00138 ** 
ti(xc,xb) 1.021     1.042   7.718       0.00627 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =   0.52   Deviance explained = 45.6%
-ML =  29379  Scale est. = 1         n = 77870
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `type="terms"` in the `predict` function, you get the contributions of the individual components to the linear predictor. However, these are not on the scale of outcome probability, but on that of the linear predictor.
Because of the non-linear transformation of the linear predictor -- in your case with the probit link -- attributing the predicted probability to the individual components requires attribution methods that come with additional assumptions.

An example of such an attribution method is [Shapley values](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shapley.html).

Comment: Thanks Christoph for the reply. From outside, the Shapley approach seems to be a black box, in any case it seems to me at first sight even more complicated to model mathematically, and with even fewer examples on the internet…perhaps I am wrong? I would really like to transcribe my gam model into an equation and understand each step, but I have not found any example as didactic and explicit as this [https://m-clark.github.io/generalized-additive-models/technical.html#a-detailed-example] for a binomial model including an interaction.